# Adding un-geotagged photo to point Mac QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, point, photos

I've followed the instructions for adding photos to points in QGIS, but it is not working. The file path shows up when the vector point is clicked on, but not the photo (see image).[image: in online instructions this attachment widget file path is supposed to show the photo here]

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?